# Metallic nanostructures exhibiting charge separation

Tags: metal, surface-chemistry, nanotechnology

Mostly ions consist of a few atoms. It is easy to see, why the solids they form must have simple stoichiometries. It is true even for polymeric ions, such as some complicated organic molecular ions as long as there are only covalent bonds inside these.

It is definitely possible to have two different metals with a miscibility gap even in their liquid state. Let's imagine one of these has higher chemical potential for electrons. Therefore opposite charges build up on their interface. Opposite charges obviously change their components' chemical potentials. In the liquid state, there is also a tendency of increasing the area of such a charged interface. However, their surface tensions may oppose that tendency.

The question is: Does this process always end with some kind of intermetallic compound with a single (possibly defected) lattice structure in some cases and complete phase segregation in those cases in which electron chemical potentials in both phases are very similar to begin with?

Any counterexample would be nice to see.
Silver subfluoride has both similarities and differences from what I'm looking for: Similarities are non-integer oxidation state and layers of silver thicker than one atom, differences are fluoride ions' non-bonding to themselves, a simple fraction stoichiometry of 2:1, and the lack of incommensurability of the lattices they form.

Comment: @PaulKolk OK, then I did not get your question. What are you asking about, really?

Comment: @IvanNeretin The possibility of something that resembles two-phase metal alloy, but forms a few-atom thick layers of incommensurable lattices spontaneously due to opposite charges on these phases.

Comment: So, you mean something like [Ag2F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_subfluoride) but fully metallic and with some charge separation between phases? No one would guess it from the title... So, better title, paragraphs, highlighting important stuff, maybe cutting out quite a bit in the beginning.

Comment: I edited title and tags based on your last comment. Check it out and edit further. This may become a useful question, but still needs work.

Comment: Would the impact of gold on the adsorption of hydrogen on magnesia be in scope? See https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp4037588.

Comment: @OscarLanzi It is relevant, even though I'm asking about macroscopic phenomenon (or a theoretical reason for the lack of such phenomenon). One may imagine these protons behave differently if a solid is built by adding more gold and magnesia-hydrogen layers on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of charge separation described in the question has been identified between hydrogen and gold, the latter a relatively electronegative metal, by Chen et al[[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp4037588)].

Hydrogen adsorbed on neat magnesia breaks up into atoms which are separately bonded to magnesium or oxygen; these hydrogen atoms are respectively polarized negatively and positively. Putting the magnesia as a thin film on silver does not change this but using a gold support instead of silver does: the gold takes up electrons from the magnesium-hydride bond, so the hydrogen remains adsorbed on the oxygen only and thus becomes entirely protic. The gold takes up the negative charge that would otherwise have been on the hydridic hydrogens. In effect a magnesia-hydrogen auride sandwich is created.

[image]

**Reference**

1. Hsin-Yi Tiffany Chen, Livia Giordano, and Gianfranco Pacchioni. "From Heterolytic to Homolytic H2 Dissociation on Nanostructured MgO(001) Films As a Function of the Metal Support." *J. Phys. Chem. C* **117**, 20, 10623–10629 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1021/jp4037588